# Firefox-extension corrupt gzip response

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox-extension: `http://mikelsv.ru/extension_ci.xpi (update: var site_url="you site/php_code.php"; in chrome\content\accelerator.js )`
PHP code: `pastebin.com/hbSNfp1e`

How work:

```
<br>
PHP: form method=post action=https://java.shadowlands.ru/zombievk/items?compress=true&lang=ru

extension: if(http-on-examine-response && url=='shadowlands...') new TracingListener();
<br>TracingListener.onDataAvailable(){ this.receivedData.push(data); }
<br>TracingListener.onStopRequest(){ send_post_data(this.receivedData.join()); to site_url; }

PHP: $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
<br> gzuncompress(base64_decode($data)));
```

Problem: gzip data corrupt. All ok if: `form action=.../items?compress=true&lang=<b>en</b>`

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I've omitted the separator argument of the [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, so the default separator (`,`) was used. I have resolved the problem by providing an empty string as a separator:

```
var responseSource = this.receivedData.join();
```

becomes:

```
var responseSource = this.receivedData.join('');
```